# where to check what is wrong about 'cannot find module' in nodejs

Tags: node.js

I pulled a project created by others years ago. I check the node_module folder,the module required is in the directory and the require stack directory showed in error message all existed.Run npm list in cmd shows no error.The only reason in my view is that the version of the module is out of date.Is that so?
**Update**:Solved after reinstalling module.

Comment: hi! welcome to stackoverflow!
let me ask some questions: which module is it? which version of nodejs you have installed? have you run `npm install`? please update your question with all the answers, thanks!

Comment: Solved after reinstalling module.

Comment: nice! congratz!